# GroupControl - BackColor não muda

Tags: c#, devexpress

Estou utilizando um `GroupControl` da DevExpress 16.1, porém ao tentar mudar a cor de fundo (backcolor) o mesmo continua com a cor default, alguem sabe o motivo? ou se estou fazendo errado?

```
        // 
        // groupControl2
        // 
        this.groupControl2.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
        this.groupControl2.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;
        this.groupControl2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(346, 314);
        this.groupControl2.Name = "groupControl2";
        this.groupControl2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(308, 156);
        this.groupControl2.TabIndex = 60;
        this.groupControl2.Text = "Fiscal";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguinte, para usar o backcolor, é necessário definir a propriedade `LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel` como false e a propriedade `LookAndFeel.Style` para Flat.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]